# After RDS Postgres Upgrade the maximum connection exceeding the limit and server is going down

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, sonarqube, amazon-rds

Dears,

I am facing on  issue. I was using Amazon ec2 instance running sonarqube which is connected to PostgresSQL RDS.

It was working fine. I upgraded PostgresSQL engine version from 10.x version to 11.21 version with the same instance type as previous db.t3.small. But after that it is exceeding the maximum connection in db and server is going down, giving 502 gateway error.

Usually, the connection won't go beyond 4 or 5. I am not able to understand why this is happening.

If someone can give me an answer it would be a great help.

Regards,

Hoping someone can help me with the above issue mentioned. This is very critical production instance.

Comment: Offtopic: Why did you upgrade to a version that will be EOL in 2 months from now? And if it's a critical production instance, hire a specialist.